# pinned vertices do no stay pinned when animating a cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have created a cape and pinned the vertices I wanted to stay stationery however when I go to animate it they unpin and repel themselves from the armor they are supposed to be near. I turned down the repel and collision distance down as far as possible and it still occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: A .blend file would be nice for better analysis.

Comment: I have pasted a link to the file

Comment: @user2389 the link is gone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cloth simulator actually uses *vertex weights* (1 = pinned and 0 = unpinned).

Your vertex group has been assigned with 0 weight, as can be seen by entering weight paint mode (blue = 0 weight):

[image]

Reassign your vertex group with the weight slider on 1 (or paint some weights in weight paint mode):

[image]

Now the vertex group will have a weight of 1 and should stay pinned.

[image]

In the cloth modifiers physics settings enable pinning and select the cape vertex group.

Comment: it still shoots away from the armor

Comment: @user2389 Hmm. in your file the cape is not near any armor at the start.. Could you possibly upload the part of the file with the cape and armor interacting?

Comment: I have figured it out I just had to pin more vertexes that were weighted

Comment: yes the original file was too large to upload so I had to Isolate the scene that was needed however when I did that it also re-adjusted the the male mesh and armor